# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-material

Am currently building an angular project with angular-datatables (an angular directive of dataTable.js) integrated. I get the attached image error showing in the browser console when I inject `<md-menu></md-menu>` of angular material into the angular-datatable in the DOM. Please view the generated error as show below
[image]

The codes work fine but I want to get rid of that annoying error in the browser console. The error is thrown only the first time the DOM loads or reloaded.

Initially, I thought that the error was thrown because jquery loads before the DOM is fully loaded until I re-positioned the javascript files including jquery at the base of the DOM just before the closing body, `</body>` tag.

This is not good for my project as stuffs may get messy as I further build. I have seen similar errors online in the course of my research but none of the provided solutions solved my problem.

Please help me out. I don't really know what am doing wrong or how to fix this. Please see also the [DEMO PROJECT](http://plnkr.co/edit/edfbkrznv1uI9u65r0Bl?p=preview) on plunker. Thank you.

Comment: what is the version of your angular material? maybe thats the issue

Comment: The version is 1.1.8. All the library versions are contained on the linked CDN in index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below two line code at line no 33024 of angular-material.js is responsible for this js error.

```
triggerElement = $element[0].querySelector('[ng-click],[ng-mouseenter]');
triggerElement.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
```

Where triggerElement is null when there is no element with ng-click or ng-mouseenter attribute inside md-menu.
So move ng-click from md-menu element to md-icon element. Use below json.

```
    [
    {
        "id":1,"firstname":"Frederick","lastname":"Eze","phone":"2348094959121","manage":
        "<md-menu><md-icon ng-click=\"$mdMenu.open($event)\" md-svg-icon=\"dots-vertical\"></md-icon><md-menu-content><md-menu-item ng-repeat=\"item in ctrl.actions\"><md-button>{{item.action}}</md-button></md-menu-item></md-menu-content></md-menu>"
    },
    {
        "id":2,"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","phone":"2348094449128","manage":"<md-menu><md-icon ng-click=\"$mdMenu.open($event)\" md-svg-icon=\"dots-vertical\"></md-icon><md-menu-content><md-menu-item ng-repeat=\"item in ctrl.actions\"><md-button>{{item.action}}</md-button></md-menu-item></md-menu-content></md-menu>"
    },
    {
        "id":3,"firstname":"Mary","lastname":"Laz","phone":"2348094956690","manage":"<md-menu><md-icon ng-click=\"$mdMenu.open($event)\" md-svg-icon=\"dots-vertical\"></md-icon><md-menu-content><md-menu-item ng-repeat=\"item in ctrl.actions\"><md-button>{{item.action}}</md-button></md-menu-item></md-menu-content></md-menu>"
    },
    {
        "id":4,"firstname":"Eunice","lastname":"Akor","phone":"2348087959125","manage":"<md-menu><md-icon ng-click=\"$mdMenu.open($event)\" md-svg-icon=\"dots-vertical\"></md-icon><md-menu-content><md-menu-item ng-repeat=\"item in ctrl.actions\"><md-button>{{item.action}}</md-button></md-menu-item></md-menu-content></md-menu>"
    },
    {
        "id":5,"firstname":"Kenneth","lastname":"Dues","phone":"2348094959178","manage":"<md-menu><md-icon ng-click=\"$mdMenu.open($event)\" md-svg-icon=\"dots-vertical\"></md-icon><md-menu-content><md-menu-item ng-repeat=\"item in ctrl.actions\"><md-button>{{item.action}}</md-button></md-menu-item></md-menu-content></md-menu>"
    }
]
```

Comment: This is just the perfect solution I was looking for. Many thanks @Chinmoy Samanta. I accept this as solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[
    {
        "id":1,"firstname":"Frederick","lastname":"Eze","phone":"2348094959121","manage":"<md-menu ><md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" ng-click=\"$mdMenu.open($event)\"><md-icon md-menu-origin=\"\" md-svg-icon=\"dots-vertical\"></md-icon></md-button><md-menu-content><md-menu-item ng-repeat=\"item in ctrl.actions\"><md-button>{{item.action}}</md-button></md-menu-item></md-menu-content></md-menu>"
    },
    {
        "id":2,"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","phone":"2348094449128","manage":"<md-menu ><md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" ng-click=\"$mdMenu.open($event)\"><md-icon md-menu-origin=\"\" md-svg-icon=\"dots-vertical\"></md-icon></md-button><md-menu-content><md-menu-item ng-repeat=\"item in ctrl.actions\"><md-button>{{item.action}}</md-button></md-menu-item></md-menu-content></md-menu>"
    },
    {
        "id":3,"firstname":"Mary","lastname":"Laz","phone":"2348094956690","manage":"<md-menu ><md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" ng-click=\"$mdMenu.open($event)\"><md-icon md-menu-origin=\"\" md-svg-icon=\"dots-vertical\"></md-icon></md-button><md-menu-content><md-menu-item ng-repeat=\"item in ctrl.actions\"><md-button>{{item.action}}</md-button></md-menu-item></md-menu-content></md-menu>"
    },
    {
        "id":4,"firstname":"Eunice","lastname":"Akor","phone":"2348087959125","manage":"<md-menu ><md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" ng-click=\"$mdMenu.open($event)\"><md-icon md-menu-origin=\"\" md-svg-icon=\"dots-vertical\"></md-icon></md-button><md-menu-content><md-menu-item ng-repeat=\"item in ctrl.actions\"><md-button>{{item.action}}</md-button></md-menu-item></md-menu-content></md-menu>"
    },
    {
        "id":5,"firstname":"Kenneth","lastname":"Dues","phone":"2348094959178","manage":"<md-menu ><md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" ng-click=\"$mdMenu.open($event)\"><md-icon md-menu-origin=\"\" md-svg-icon=\"dots-vertical\"></md-icon></md-button><md-menu-content><md-menu-item ng-repeat=\"item in ctrl.actions\"><md-button>{{item.action}}</md-button></md-menu-item></md-menu-content></md-menu>"
    }
]
```

Moved the click function to

```
<md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" ng-click=\"$mdMenu.open($event)\"><md-icon md-menu-origin=\"\" md-svg-icon=\"dots-vertical\"></md-icon></md-button>
```

Comment: Gratitude @Ininiv the solution worked but I did not want to use `<md-button class="md-icon-button"></md-button>` as part of the trigger DOM element because of the extra padding or size it adds to `<md-icon></md-icon>` on the DOM. However, this silenced the errors and I accept it as solution to it. What chinmoy Samanta said did the trick without further adjustment to the DOM.

Comment: I mean to say I have up voted the answer because I can only accept one

Answer (score 0):

Just replace **line no 42** in **"services.js"** file with below code

```
if(iElement.assignedSlot){
$compile(iElement.contents())(scope);
}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: thanks for the effort but your code fails to compile the angular-material  directive, `<md-menu></md-menu>`. The svg icons failed to appear.

Answer (score -3):

Try changing the value to something else than `null`.